# how to originate a call with freeswitch esl?

Tags: .net, freeswitch

im trying to do the simplest outgoing call to a simple phone number with esl. but nothing seems to work

i get incoming events and i can issue different commands (`answer`,`conference`) etc. but `originate` simply doesnt do a thing

most online info has loads of different options that are at the moment unimportant for me. for now i just need to get the call out. i guess i can always add additional options later.

heres the stripped down code (im trying different versions)

```
SwitchApi("originate", "sofia/external/1011@mydomain.com")
SwitchApi("originate", "sofia/external/17181112222@mydomain.com")
SwitchApi("originate", "sofia/external/17181112222")

Function SwitchApi(Command As String, Arg As String) As ESLevent
    Dim esl = FreeSwitch.Api(Command, Arg)
    Return esl
End Function
```

ive also tried `freeswitch.api` and `freeswitch.bgapi` if it makes any difference

all these calls and some others ive tried return something like

> -USAGE: <'call url> <'exten>|&<'application_name>(<'app_args>) [<'dialplan>] [<'context>] [<'cid_name>] [<'cid_num>] [<'timeout_sec>]

also they dont even show up in the freeswitch log

any help is greatly appreciated

thanks!

**SOLUTION**

this is the line that works

```
SwitchApi("originate", "sofia/gateway/mygateway/1718111222 &park()")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, the error message is completely correct: the `originate` API needs an application to execute on the outbound call. This could be `&playback()` or `&park()` or something else.

See some working examples in my scripts on github:

- https://github.com/voxserv/freeswitch-perf-dialer/blob/master/dialer.pl
- https://github.com/voxserv/freeswitch-helper-scripts/tree/master/esl
- https://github.com/voxserv/rring/blob/master/lib/Rring/Caller/FreeSWITCH.pm

Comment: thanks a million! that was exactly it. im adding the solution to the question (for posterity...)